# Select all the values from a drag and drop Listbox in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui in tkinter where I will have a Listbox and be able to drag and drop files into it. How can I store all the items inside this listbox in a list with a command on the button?

```
lb = tk.Listbox(root, height=8)
lb.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
lb.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", lambda e: lb.insert(tk.END, e.data))
lb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit")
btn.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

Comment: You can assign a callback using `command` option of the button and call `lb.get(0, tk.END)` to get all the items of the listbox inside the callback.

Comment: @acw1668 Hi, can you provide please more details because it is a blackbox to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to assign a callback to the `command` option of the button, then you can use `lb.get(0, tk.END)` to get the item list inside the callback:

```py
...
def submit():
    # in case you need to access itemlist outside this function
    global itemlist
    # get all the items inside the listbox to itemlist
    itemlist = lb.get(0, tk.END)
    print(itemlist)

# assign a callback via command option
btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
btn.grid(row=2, column=0)
...
```